# How to transfer a VM between two physically connected ESXI servers?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, esxi

I have two Dell PowerEdge T440s, each with ESXI Version 7 update 2.

These are meant to act as a redundant pair and should have identical copies of the same VM on both in case one crashes the other can take over.

We did not want to copy over any VM's until after we were done with our development of the VM's which we have recently concluded.

The two PowerEdges have a gigabit port that has an ethernet directly connecting the two servers.  The intent is if that if for whatever reason a hot fix is done on a VM it can then be quickly transferred over to the other VM to keep things identical.

However, how can I actually do that transfer in the first place?  I've seen some videos that have a migrate button as an option the Virtual Machine section of the ESXI interface but I don't see it.  One promising option seems to be creating it from the data store - but is there a way to directly get a copy of a VM from Server 1 into the datastore for Server 2 and vice versa?  Any help is appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Migration would only exist if you linked both instances of ESXi to a single instance of VSphere and even then you would only have one copy of the VM. So you’re limited to downloading the VM and uploading the VM yourself. How you access your data store is dependent on your infrastructure

Comment: Ok.  The way that the person who had us make it would prefer to do it is from inside one of the VM's using VMWare converter and just making sure it's able to see both servers, so we are doing that way.  Appreciate the reply.